# Online audio streaming websites are not working properly on WebView

Tags: android, webview, audio-streaming

I try to play online audio songs from online audio streaming websites like `gaana.com` or `saavn.com` etc. on `WebView`.

**My Code:**

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://gaana.com/");
```

Websites are loaded in webview correctly but the problem is that **when I click on play(for any song) nothing will happen.** i.e, no any response show in webview.

**My manifest file:**

```
<manifest package="biz.coolpage.aashish.app"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="biz.coolpage.aashish.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Translucent.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for help guys in advance.

Comment: You can provide manifest file?

Comment: @MeosCoder I added my manifest file in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`
into `activity` tag in `manifest`.
And then add code:

```
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://gaana.com");
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

`webSettings.setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?